# open file in file manager android

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I saw many similar question, but no one help me!

So, I want to get list of available file managers, and when user pick ones, open folder in this file manager, where necessary file located. File can be any extension.

I try like this:

```
s=Uri.fromFile(File object);

...

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("file/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
intent.setData(s);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

.. but this throw ActivityNotFoundException.

Please, help me. Thanks!

I call `StartActivity` from `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, I have function, wich create dialog and return. One more point, when I don't `setData`, programm is working and give list of file manager to user, but it's open root directory, not directory of file.

```
private  Dialog createAlertDialog( final Context context,   final Uri s) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogArg, int which) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("file/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
                intent.setData(s);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener onCloseDialog = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogArg, int which) {

                }
        };

        dialog = builder.setPositiveButton(MyApp.getCustomAppContext().getString(R.string.ok), onClickListener)
                        .setNegativeButton(MyApp.getCustomAppContext().getString(R.string.cancel), onCloseDialog)
                        .setMessage(MyApp.getCustomAppContext().getString(R.string.open_explorer))
                        .create();
        return dialog;
    }
```

And in Log I have this:

```
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to 
 handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] 
  dat=file:///toptoptop/Noize%20MC%20Bring-Bring-Bring.mp4 }
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult
(Instrumentation.java:1409)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity
(Instrumentation.java:1379)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult
(Activity.java:2827)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at com.serbinvitaly.copyeraser.ResultsActivity$4.onClick
(ResultsActivity.java:171)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-13 11:06:47.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14534):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 11:06:47.226: WARN/ActivityManager(7260):   Force finishing activity com.serbinvitaly.copyeraser/.ResultsActivity
09-13 11:06:47.230: ERROR/(7260): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Answer (score 0):

try remove context.startActivity(intent) and chage on this.startActivity(intent). Or please give me more source code. And logs.

Comment: that would not explain and activitynotfoundexception

Answer (score 0):

The case is simple - Android sees no activity to handle your request based on your intent criteria. Like it or not :) If you are sure there's something installed on your device that should open your file (and that app opens for others) you may try to install [Intent Intercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept) app and see that is their intent that works vs. yours that does not.

You should always use `try/catch` while trying to invoke external activity. Do not assume there is any or that you are allowed to call it. So it should be:

```
try {
  startActivity(intent);
} catch( Exception e ) {
   // show toask to the user
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but in my phone installed 5 different file managers. Intent Intercept don't find my intent.

Comment: I understand, that system hasn't activity, which can open my intent. But which intent, I must to send, that file manager will find it??

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem when using this line:

```
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

Remove that line and everything should be fine again.